# SQL Server: Create default stored procedure as and when a new database is created

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I need one simple stored procedure to be created by default, as and when a new database is created in SQL Server. How can I achieve this? Assume the stored procedure to be created is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Default_SP]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT GETDATE()
END
```

Triggers can be applied on the table level. But this is on database create event. I searched over the net and I could not find answers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create the procedure in the system database model.

From [model Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388.aspx)

> The model database is used as the template for all databases created
>   on an instance of SQL Server.

Comment: That's what I would do too. Other solutions would be to have a scheduled job looking for/creating the SP into each DB at regular intervals. Or you could try for a server-level trigger (forgot the name. DLL or DDL trigger I think) but I never did it myself.